# Помогите декодировать

Tags: python, utf-8, blob, decode

Роюсь с базой данных и там есть формат данных BLOB - никак не могу декодировать.
Помогите пожалуйста

```
test =b"v10\xbb\x03^\xe8\xd0i\xa0\xd6/\x8d\x9c]\xd8{2\xf4g\x9c7\x07:\x81\x88\x87\xceX\xd9\x98"
print(test.decode('utf-8'))
```

Вылазит ошибка:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Comment: 0xbb  это BOM символ. Воспользуйтесь кодеком utf-8-sig, чтобы прочитать информацию вместе с BOM символом

Comment: А почему вы считаете что у вас в этом blob лежит текст ? Как по мне, это некие двоичные данные, которые в текст не переводятся

Comment: @Mike, я в программе для просмотра db посмотрел формат

Comment: @nukee, не работает *(

Comment: Если с опцией ignore прогнать декодер `print(test.decode("utf-8-sig", "ignore"))`, то ничего вразумительного `v10^i/]{2g7:X٘`. При этом часть символов игнорится. Можно вместо ignore поставить replace. Есть идеи, что там лежит внутри?

Comment: @AndyPavlov , это база данных login data (все пароли которые запомнил браузер)

Comment: Это хеш может быть?

Comment: @ВладДутчак посмотрите https://github.com/ohyicong/decrypt-chrome-passwords и https://ohyicong.medium.com/how-to-hack-chrome-password-with-python-1bedc167be3d

Comment: `test =b"v10\xbb\x03^\xe8 ... ` - это полный объём данных? Возможно, там лежит что-то сжатое и после распаковки станет ясно, что за данные.

Comment: Если это пароли, то поле БД скорее всего зашифровано и это тогда действительно двоичные данные, а не текст

Comment: Попробовал через `chardet` определить кодировку - тоже ничего вразумительного. Похоже двоичные данные таки.